# Redux Dispatch Not Working in Action Creator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have the following action creator(s) and for some reason, the code within the *dispatch* doesn't execute, although I know that the *loginSuccess()* gets invoked because the first alert triggers. What am I doing wrong?

```
import facebook from '../api/facebook'
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';

export function loginSuccess() {
  alert("This alerts fine");
  return dispatch => {
    alert("This doesn't alert");
  }
}
```

I am using Thunk (or at least think I am correctly) as can be seen below when creating the store.

```
import App from './containers/App';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store';
import createReducer from './reducers';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import Parse from 'parse/react-native';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import Settings from './settings';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import logger from 'redux-logger'

const settings = Settings.load();

const middleware = [ thunk, logger() ]

const store = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
)

function setup() {
    class Root extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <App />
                </Provider>
            );
         }
    }

    return Root;
}

module.exports = setup;
```

The component that is invoking `loginSuccess()` is shown below...

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component,PropTypes } from 'react';
import { loginSuccess,loginError } from '../../../actions/application'
import {
 LoginButton,
 GraphRequest,
 GraphRequestManager,
 GraphRequestConfig,
} from 'react-native-fbsdk'


class FacebookLogin extends Component {

_onLoginSuccess(result){
    loginSuccess();
};

_onLoginError(error){
    loginError();
}

_onLoginCancelled(){

}

render(){
  return (
    <View>
      <LoginButton
        readPermissions={["email","public_profile","user_friends"]}
        onLoginFinished={
          (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
              this._onLoginError(error);
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
              this._onLoginCancelled();
            } else {
              this._onLoginSuccess(result);
            }
          }
        }
        onLogoutFinished={() => alert("User logged out")}/>
    </View>
  );
}
}

FacebookLogin.propTypes = {
  navigator: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default FacebookLogin;
```

Comment: Since you are returning a function from the action creator, I assume you are using `redux-thunk` middleware for `redux`

Comment: @VarunGupta I believe I am, but how can I verify that I am using it?

Comment: You must be adding it when you create the store in the list of middlewares that you want to apply to the store. Check this page http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html

Comment: @VarunGupta See Edit Above, As far as I know, I am doing this correctly.

Comment: I think it looks correct. How do you know that the code within the dispatch is not executed. Maybe `facebook.getUser` is not completed. You can put a console.log in the callback to confirm that it is completed. Also, you are checking `if(error)` but error is not defined. So, it will never go in there.

Comment: Can you include the code of the component from where `loginSuccess` is being called?

Comment: @VarunGupta The `facebook.GetUser` is irrelevant as the alert before it is not even hit.

Comment: @Deadfish I have updated with calling component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in the `FacebookLogin` component.

- The component is not connected to `redux`. Do something like `export default connect()(FacebookLogin)`. You will need to import `connect` from `react-redux`
- You need to dispatch the `loginSuccesss` action instead of directly calling it. So, you will need to do something like `this.props.dispatch(loginSuccess())`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can dispatch function when you are using thunk middleware but next function should resolve to dispatching action. If you want to just call alert you do not have use dispatch for it.

```
export function loginSuccess() {
  alert("This alerts fine");
  return dispatch => {
    type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
    alertText: 'This doesn't alert'
  }
}
```

Or

```
export function loginSuccess() {
  alert("This alerts fine");
  alertAction("This doesn't alert");
}

const alertAction = (text) => (dispatch) => ({
  type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
  alertText: text
})
```