# Dispatch redux not executed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-final-form

I'm trying to submit a form when a user signUp. When the submit button clicked an action creator should executed to start an asynchronous action but actually the submit is not triggered and the action creator is not launched.

actions.ts:

```
import { ActionTypes } from "./types";
import { SignUpUser, User } from "../apis/authentication";
import { AxiosError } from "axios";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";

export interface ReturnedUser {
  username: string;
}
export interface SignUpSuccessAction {
  type: ActionTypes.SucceedSignUp;
  payload: ReturnedUser;
}

export interface SignUpFailAction {
  type: ActionTypes.FailSignUp;
  payload: string;
}

export interface SignUpStartAction {
  type: ActionTypes.StartSignUp;
}

const signUpStarted = (): SignUpStartAction => ({
  type: ActionTypes.StartSignUp
});

const signUpSucceeded = (user: ReturnedUser): SignUpSuccessAction => ({
  type: ActionTypes.SucceedSignUp,
  payload: user
});

const signUpFailed = (error: string): SignUpFailAction => ({
  type: ActionTypes.FailSignUp,
  payload: error
});

export const signUpFetch = (user: User) => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(signUpStarted());
    SignUpUser(user).then(
      (response: any) => {
        const { username } = response;
        return dispatch(signUpSucceeded(username));
      },
      (error: AxiosError) => {
        let errorMessage = "Internal Server Error";
        if (error.response) {
          errorMessage = error.response.data;
        }
        return dispatch(signUpFailed(errorMessage));
      }
    );
  };
};
```

reducers/reducer.ts:

```
import { Action, ActionTypes } from "../actions";

export const SignUpReducer = (state = {}, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.SucceedSignUp:
      return { ...state, user: action.payload };

    case ActionTypes.FailSignUp:
      return { ...state, error: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

reducers/index.ts:

```
import { SignUpReducer } from "./signUp";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

export const reducer = combineReducers({
  signUp: SignUpReducer
});
```

index.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import SignUp from "./containers/Signup/SignUp";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { reducer } from "./reducers/index";

const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

const App = () => <SignUp />;
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

SignUp.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Form, Field } from "react-final-form";
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import CardWrapper from "../../components/CardWrapper";
import PasswordField from "../../components/Password";
import TextField from "../../components/TextField";
import { validate, submit } from "./validation";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    container: {
      padding: 16,
      margin: "auto",
      maxWidth: "100%",
      flexGrow: 1
    },
    paper: {
      padding: 16
    },
    item: {
      marginTop: 16
    }
  })
);

const SignUp = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [showPassword, setPassword] = useState(false);

  const handleClickShowPassword = () => {
    setPassword(!showPassword);
  };

  const handleMouseDownPassword = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>
  ) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <Form
        onSubmit={submit}
        validate={validate}
        render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <CardWrapper title='SignUp Form'>
              <Grid container justify='center' spacing={3}>
                <Grid item md={12}>
                  <Field fullWidth required name='username'>
                    {props => (
                      <TextField
                        label='Username'
                        type='text'
                        value={props.input.value}
                        onChange={props.input.onChange}
                        onBlur={props.input.onBlur}
                        meta={props.meta}
                        fullWidth={true}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Field>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item md={12}>
                  <Field fullWidth required name='email'>
                    {props => (
                      <TextField
                        label='Email'
                        type='email'
                        value={props.input.value}
                        onChange={props.input.onChange}
                        onBlur={props.input.onBlur}
                        meta={props.meta}
                        fullWidth={true}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Field>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item md={12}>
                  <Field fullWidth required name='password'>
                    {props => (
                      <PasswordField
                        value={props.input.value}
                        handleChange={props.input.onChange}
                        showPassword={showPassword}
                        handleClickShowPassword={handleClickShowPassword}
                        handleMouseDownPassword={handleMouseDownPassword}
                        fullWidth={true}
                        onBlur={props.input.onBlur}
                        meta={props.meta}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Field>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item className={classes.item}>
                  <Button
                    type='button'
                    variant='contained'
                    onClick={form.reset}
                    disabled={submitting || pristine}
                  >
                    Reset
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item className={classes.item}>
                  <Button
                    variant='contained'
                    color='primary'
                    type='submit'
                    disabled={submitting || pristine}
                  >
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </CardWrapper>
          </form>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect()(SignUp);
```

validation.ts:

```
interface SignUpValues {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  username: string;
}

const submit = (values: SignUpValues) => {
  const user = {
    username: values.username,
    email: values.email,
    password: values.password
  };

  return signUpFetch(user);
};
export { submit };
```

I find a similar question posted about the same issue described by [Redux Dispatch Not Working in Action Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758366/redux-dispatch-not-working-in-action-creator) but the answer does not fix my problem. Does I make something wrong when linking the different component with redux?

Comment: Yes, you have to add the action within the connect function as second parameter (mapDispatchToProps) and call that prop from within your component. Please read the [docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components)

Answer (score 0):

It wont dispatch because in component You didnt dispatch Your function

```
return signUpFetch(user)
```

Instead Connect the component with Redux and dispatch the function
in Index.tsx

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 const mapDispatchToProps = {
    submit
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUp);
```

And access it with

> this.props.submit

Add dispatch in Submit function

```
const submit = (values: SignUpValues) =>(dispatch, getState)=> {
  const user = {
    username: values.username,
    email: values.email,
    password: values.password
  };

  return dispatch(signUpFetch(user));
};
```

Whenever you need to update redux state, dispatch the function from where it is also called and also in the actions.

Comment: submit is a function not component

Comment: Ok then Dispatch in submit also and  dispatch where submit is called from

Comment: Wait i will edit my answer you will able to understand clearly

Comment: The other one too?

Comment: Both.It's the first time that I use react-final-form with typescript and things confuse me now.

Comment: Typescript returns errors whenever I want to add dispatch but when I fixed them the submit does not works and react-final-form does not mention any clear example how to connect the form to redux-store

Comment: connect your component with redux not your form , check weather you have installed redux package

Comment: Accroding to an example of react-final-form it mentioned that  `If you need to mutate your data via dispatching Redux actions, you should probably use Redux Form.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to connection the component to the store when you do the dispatch:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const submit = (values: SignUpValues) => {
  const user = {
    username: values.username,
    email: values.email,
    password: values.password
  };

  return this.props.signUpFetch(user);
};
export const connectedSubmit =  connect(null, {signUpFetch})(submit);
```

```
import { validate, connectedSubmit as submit } from "./validation";
```

And also you can just return at `SignUpUser`

```
export const signUpFetch = (user: User) => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(signUpStarted());
    return SignUpUser(user).then(
      (response: any) => {
        const { username } = response;
        dispatch(signUpSucceeded(username));
      },
      (error: AxiosError) => {
        let errorMessage = "Internal Server Error";
        if (error.response) {
          errorMessage = error.response.data;
        }
        dispatch(signUpFailed(errorMessage));
      }
    );
  };
}
```